# Predicting binary values with binary independent variables in logistic regression

Tags: logistic

I have two variables both are binary.

I would like to see how well one predicts the other.

Is it possible to do this in logistic regression? variables are coded as 0 and 1 but 1 does not indicate that something is  'correct'. can I still use logistic regression to see how well it is predicted?

Answer (score 5):

You can, but you can get all the information you need from the simpler Chi-Square test and/or from a Phi correlation.  Easier to conduct and more straightforward to interpret and report results.

Comment: so I can run a simple chi square on two binary variables with around 160 values?

Comment: @rolando2, could you show an example of where chi-square / phi correlation would be better than logistic regression for estimating effects of other binaries? I use logistic regression on survey data quite frequently `1=increasing / 0=decreasing ~ personality attributes (0 or 1)...` to understand the effect of personality attributes on likelihood to increase or decrease business with a company.

Comment: @Brandon I won't say "better" in an absolute sense, but better in the ways I mentioned.

Comment: @Daniel In your original post you indicated that your variables took on one of only 2 values--0 or 1.  Do you mean 160 cases rather than 160 values?  If so, yes, you can run a Chi-Square test in that situation.